# How to perform "tracert" like operation from browser?

Tags: windows-xp, troubleshooting

I'm remotely investigating issue with my friend's WIN XP computer. The browsers (Chrome and IE) won't show any pages but message with err_connection_reset in details.

I've tried to perform "telnet google.com 80" and send there "HEAD / HTTP/1.0" from console and everything went fine, but browsers refused to give me anything. I've checked for presence of firewalls and proxy servers in the settings, but nothing seems to be there. What else to check?

Comment: Can you use basic network commands? Like are you able to ping 8.8.8.8? Are you able to ping www.google.de? Is it only the browser not working? Eg are you able to use E-Mail Client like Thunderbird or other applications connecting to the internet? Did you try to reinstall chrome?

Comment: Running Avast Antivirus by chance? Might also look at trying with TLS1.1 disabled in IE, and/or incognito mode in Chrome as tests. And just in case you haven't clear browsing cache.

Comment: @IvanViktorovic I can use everything, but browsers.

Comment: Like i said try reinstall chrome or may try firefox.